# Dynamically update the value of form as user types input before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help dynamically updating the value of form submit as user types input field.

```
 <form>
  <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value = 0 />     
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>


<script>
 var amount = 100;
 var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
 var total = amount + number;
 var a = document.getElementById("submit");
 a.value = "Pay $" + total;

</script>
```

Right now, the value of submit is "Pay 100". But when user enters 4 in number field, I want it to say "Pay 104" as he types 4. I also want user to delete and enter different number and the value changes accordingly. How would I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I apologize, I flagged this as unclear, but after re-reading, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener("input", function(){
  if(this.value.length && !isNaN(parseInt(this.value))){
    var total = amount + parseInt(this.value);
    submit.value = "Pay $"+ total;
  }
}, false);
```

```js
var amount = 100;
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener("input", function(){
  if(this.value.length && !isNaN(parseInt(this.value))){
    var total = amount + parseInt(this.value);
    submit.value = "Pay $"+ total;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value = 0 />     
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```